# make a file on qtopia errors

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to compile a program on a friendlyARM qtopia 2.2.0
but I getting some errors and quite frankly I don't know what I am doing.

Makefile code:

```
IDIR =./
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =./

LIBS=-lgd -lrt

_DEPS = main.h Makefile
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o serial.o fb.o menu_main.o timer.o cmdin.o buzzer.o statemachine.o inout.o network.o text_file_input.o text_file_input_oven.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

error codes:

```
/sdcard/images/makef # Makefile
Makefile: line 1: IDIR: not found
Makefile: line 3: IDIR: not found
Makefile: line 6: LDIR: not found
Makefile: line 8: -lrt: not found
Makefile: line 10: _DEPS: not found
Makefile: line 11: IDIR: not found
Makefile: line 11: _DEPS: not found
Makefile: line 11: patsubst: not found
Makefile: line 11: DEPS: not found
Makefile: line 13: _OBJ: not found
Makefile: line 14: ODIR: not found
Makefile: line 14: _OBJ: not found
Makefile: line 14: patsubst: not found
Makefile: line 14: OBJ: Permission denied
Makefile: line 17: ODIR: not found
Makefile: line 17: DEPS: not found
Makefile: line 17: /%.o:: not found
Makefile: line 18: CC: not found
Makefile: line 18: CFLAGS: not found
Makefile: line 18: can't open : no such file
Makefile: line 18: -c: not found
Makefile: line 20: OBJ: Permission denied
Makefile: line 20: main:: not found
Makefile: line 21: CFLAGS: not found
Makefile: line 21: LIBS: not found
Makefile: line 21: gcc: not found
Makefile: line 23: .PHONY:: not found
Makefile: line 25: clean:: not found
Makefile: line 26: ODIR: not found
Makefile: line 26: INCDIR: not found
```

Comment: Eh... why is this tagged C#?

Comment: sorry its C+ updated the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute the Makefile file itself. You need to use the `make` command.

Comment: when i use "make -f Makefile" i get this error "bin/sh: make: not found" there is a "sh" file in the bin folder but it look like i need to install some more stuff, any markers on this ?

Comment: You probably need to install `make` on your system.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but this is probably a stupid question but how do I install make